# codeigniter 4 email not sending

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeIgniter 4 with xampp, I have problem of sending email using smtp protocol.

`Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

I configured the php.ini and sendmail.ini in xampp and the same error occurred please help

```
Date: Sat, 19 Sep 2020 16:12:50 -0500
From: <xxxxxxx>
Return-Path: <xxxxx>
To: received mail
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=45=6D=61=69=6C=20=54=65=73=74?=
Reply-To: <sender mail>
User-Agent: codeigniter
X-Sender: sender mail
X-Mailer:codeigniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Please provide more details of your application. Also you could try a google search, which will yield a good amount of similar cases and answers.

Comment: The error says it all. Your server is not properly configured to send mails. Do some research on how you can setup SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using phpmailer and add it to you Helpers folder.